# Ruby on Rails Tutorial -- strange uses of upcase/downcase and case-insensitivity

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, railstutorial.org

Working my way through Michael Hartl's excellent [tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-book) for Ruby on Rails. I'm at the point where he creates a test that checks for duplicate email addresses, and I'm a little confused about his use of upcase, downcase, and case-insensitive checks.

The test (Listing 6.17) looks like this:

```
describe User do
  before do
    @user = User.new(name: "Example User", email: "user@example.com")
  end
  .
  .
  .
  describe "when email address is already taken" do
    before do
      user_with_same_email = @user.dup
      user_with_same_email.email = @user.email.upcase
      user_with_same_email.save
    end

    it { should_not be_valid }
  end
end
```

Note the call to `upcase`. All fine. But in his validity check (6.18), he sets case sensitivity ***off***.

```
validates :email, presence: true, format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                    uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

What? Why did he convert the copy to uppercase if he was going to do a case-insensitive validation?

Finally, in 6.20, he sets up a `before_save` block that converts a new user's email to lowercase.

```
before_save { self.email = email.downcase }
```

That makes perfect sense, because you want lowercase in your database. But I'm confused as to why he used uppercase in the test, given that the save is going to convert the email address to lowercase anyway. Am I missing something obvious?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

seems to me that by converting to upper case, and storing the data as lower case, you make sure they're not equivalent, so the "case_sensitive:false" part of the validator will really be tested.

Answer (score 2):

Checking that `@user.email.upcase` is invalid ensures the uniqueness of this value no matter what the case is.
When you write `uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }` you force uniqueness, no matter what the case is: "foo" is equivalent to "fOO".
As for the `before_save` it might be a bit overkill to set it and also a validation case insensitive, but at least it show you the goal:
Email has to be unique, no matter the case, that is the validation. On the other hand you store everything lowercase, this is the data part.

Answer (score 1):

The test is (a bit silently, it's not in the description) asserting that case is ignored when checking uniqueness. Which is a sensible behaviour for email addresses in general.

The lower-case "normalisation" for stored data, plus removing case-sensitivity from the validation, seems like overkill, but *may* be required due to sequence of events when validating as opposed to saving. Either way, it is self-consistent to have a uniqueness constraint that ignores case, whilst canonicalising the email addresses to lower case for storage.